# Using PUT to update several JSON data in one request

Tags: json, rest, go, go-gin

I followed this guide [Developing a simple CRUD API with Go, Gin and Gorm](https://medium.com/@cgrant/developing-a-simple-crud-api-with-go-gin-and-gorm-df87d98e6ed1) to build my first RESTful service in golang, I can read parameter(s) from my web service, and update one value of parameter, But how to parse the JSON to update several values of parameters at one PUT request.

The CURL command I intend to use for my test as bellow

```
$ curl -i -X PUT http://localhost:8080/params -d '{ [ {"id":"1","value": "10"}, {"id":"2","value": "20"}] }'
```

Following is my code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/gin-contrib/cors"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"

    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

type Param struct {
    ID    int    `json:"id" `
    Name  string `json:"name"`
    Title string `json:"title"`
    Value string `json:"value"`
}

type ParamValue struct {
    ID int `json:"id" `
    // Name  string `json:"name"`
    // Title string `json:"title"`
    Value string `json:"value"`
}

var db *gorm.DB
var err error

func main() {

    db, err = gorm.Open("mysql", "user:password@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/test?charset=utf8&parseTime=True&loc=Local")

    defer db.Close()

    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err.Error())
    }

    db.AutoMigrate(&Param{})

    r := gin.Default()

    r.GET("/params", GetParams)
    r.GET("/params/:id", GetParam)
    r.PUT("/params/:id", UpdateParam)
    r.PUT("/params", UpdateParams) // How to implement this one

    r.Use(cors.Default())
    r.Run()
}

func GetParams(c *gin.Context) {
    var params []Param
    if err := db.Find(&params).Error; err != nil {
        c.AbortWithStatus(404)
    } else {
        c.JSON(200, params)
    }
}

func GetParam(c *gin.Context) {
    id := c.Params.ByName("id")
    var param Param
    if err := db.Where("id = ?", id).First(&param).Error; err != nil {
        c.AbortWithStatus(404)
    } else {
        c.JSON(200, param)
    }
}

func UpdateParams(c *gin.Context) {
    // Debug info
    fmt.Println("c.Request.Method >> " + c.Request.Method)
    fmt.Println("c.Request.URL.String() >> " + c.Request.URL.String())
    // command for testing
    // $ curl -i -X PUT http://localhost:8080/params -d '{ [ {"id":"1","value": "10"}, {"id":"2","value": "20"}] }'
}

func UpdateParam(c *gin.Context) {
    var param Param
    id := c.Params.ByName("id")

    if err := db.Where("id = ?", id).First(&param).Error; err != nil {
        c.AbortWithStatus(404)
    } else {
        name := param.Name // readonly
        c.BindJSON(&param)
        if param.Name != name { // if changed
            param.Name = name   // restore the origin
        }
        db.Save(&param)
        c.JSON(200, param)
    }

    // $ curl -i -X PUT http://localhost:8080/params/63 -d '{ "name": "recharge", "title": "switch 0/1:on/off", "value": "1"}'
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `{ [ {"id":"1" "value": "10"}, {"id":"2" "value": "20"}] }`
Is this a valid json? I doubt that

Answer (score 1):

first of all, you json is invalid.
I guess that this is what you wanted:

> [{"id":"1" ,"value": "10"}, {"id":"2" ,"value": "20"}]

an easier solution will be to add an struct that match your json:

and then add the json.Unmarshal to parse the json:

```
jsn := `[{"id":"1" ,"value": "10"}, {"id":"2" ,"value": "20"}]`
var data yourSturctName
json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsn), &data)
for _, r := range data {
    fmt.Printf("ID:%s Value:%s", r.ID, r.Value)
}
```

then add that into your logic.